# Question on derivative under integral sign

Tags: integration, derivatives

Is the function $f(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cos \ tx}{x^{2}+1}dx$ not differentiable at $t=0$, but differentiable everywhere else?

This may have some explanation using Fourier Transforms, but I wanted to see a more "basic" explanation for it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: For $t \neq 0$, you can make the substitution $y = \lvert t\rvert\cdot x$. You get $$f(t) = \lvert t\rvert \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos y}{y^2+t^2}\,dy.$$ This makes it clear that $f$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ (and you can differentiate under the integral as often as you please in that form). The form hints at a problem at $0$, but it's not entirely obvious how bad a problem it is.

Comment: The integral diverges when $t=0$, as $y\rightarrow 0$, and that sure points to an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the right-derivative at zero you may write for $t>0$ (and substitute $u=xt$):
$$ \frac{f(0)-f(t)}{t} = 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^2+1} \frac{dx}{t} =
\int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin^2(u/2)}{u^2+t^2} du \rightarrow -f'_+(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin^2(u/2)}{u^2} du  >0 $$
as $t$ goes to zero. On the other hand, by symmetry, $f_-'(0)=-f'_+(0)$ so $f$ is not differentiable at zero.

Answer (score 1):

With some contour integration, this is a fairly straightforward integration. We can find that:
$$f(t) = \frac{\pi e^{-|t|}}{2}$$
Then, taking the derivative of that:
$$f'(t) = \frac{-\pi t e^{-|t|}}{2|t|}$$
By taking the limits of the derivative, we find the derivative doesn't exist at $t = 0$.

Comment: $(\not\exists\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x))\ne(\not\exists f'(0))$, but you can use the definition of derivative.